# GIF random behaviour on Firefox10

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, counter, gif

I am using this to start an gif image counter to animate down from 3 to 1. On all browsers, except Firefox 10 is working fine, but on Firefox very often it skips 3 and stars directly from 2

```
$('#counter-gif').attr('src', $('#counter-gif').attr('src'));
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work properly on firefox? thanks

i'm using that line of code because the counter is inside an success method of an ajax which I run multiple times and every time I need to restart the counter and re-setting the src leads to restarting the animation. thanks

Comment: So you're changing the src of an image to itself? I'm confused as to what it is that you're attempting to do.

Comment: yes.. in this way the animation of the gif restarts

Comment: I dunno if it's because it's Monday, but your question is vague to me. Maybe if you posted the rest of your code or a jsFiddle you would get more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start your timer on the `onload` event:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { setTimeout("doSomething();", 3000); }
img src="somegif.gif";
```

However this is based on my own assumptions on what you're trying to do. You haven't explained things properly. Your sample code set's the source of the gif to... the source of itself. So that lince of code is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is all the relevant code:

```
success: function (data) { // after ajax
  $('#counter-gif').attr('src', $('#counter-gif').attr('src')); 
  // this one starts the counter, but on firefox it starts from 2 not from 3, it is like it takes more to load the gif until it starts the animation
  // bunch of unrelated code that treats the response
}
```